# If a programming language does not support method overriding then what inconveniences the programmer might face?

Tags: oop, overriding

Theoretically, Child class can't override parent class' methods if needed. But How does it actually affect in practical aspect? What issues the programmer will face?

Comment: People code in languages that don't have inheritance at all all the time.

Comment: but if oop don't provide overriding like java restrict overloading? Then what will be the practical issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example in Java

```
public class Mammal {
    public final int getNumberOfLegs() {
        return 4;
    }
}

public class Human extends Mammal {
    @Override                        <<-- compilation error!
    public int getNumberOfLegs() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Here I have declared `Mammal`'s method `getNumberOfLegs()` to be `final`, which means that it is not permitted to override the method in a child class.

- When I try to override it in a child class, I get a compilation error.
- If I *need* to override it (as in this example where people have an unusual number of legs), then I have a big problem.

Now imagine what would happen if Java didn't allow me to override *any* methods in a child class.  I would not be able to implement any methods with a different behavior in a child class.

- In some simple cases I will be able to work around this.  (In this one, I could add a `numberOfLegs` field to all `Mammal` objects.)
- In other cases it would be more difficult to share common behavior in a class hierarchy.  (In my contrived example, you can imagine that I didn't anticipate that `getNumberOfLegs()` *might* need to be implemented differently in a child class.)  Now clearly you can change behavior by modifying the code the parent class rather than overriding it in a child class.  However:

  - this reduces your options as a programmer, and
  - it also leads to parent classes having too much knowledge about current and (possible) future child classes.